# Hide div's on page load

Tags: jquery, html

I'm trying to figure out why I can't hide two div elements with jquery when the page loads. When one of two buttons in pressed I want the relevant div to be shown. This works fine but I can't seem to hide them before either button is pressed.

I have tried putting  `$('.gauge1').hide();` at the start of the code but it stops the div's ever appearing. See my [fiddle here](https://jsfiddle.net/jsykes/9oz4nwLp/3/)

```js
$(document).ready(function() {

  //How to ihide them both on page load?



  $("#button1").on("click", function() {
    $('.gauge1').fadeIn();
    $('.gauge2').hide();
  });

  $("#button2").on("click", function() {
    $('.gauge2').fadeIn();
    $('.gauge1').hide();
  });


  var d = new JustGage({
    id: "gauge1",
    value: 67,
    min: 0,
    max: 100,
    title: "Visitors"
  });
  var b = new JustGage({
    id: "gauge2",
    value: 91,
    min: 0,
    max: 100,
    title: "Visitors"
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="//cdn.jsdelivr.net/raphael/2.1.2/raphael-min.js"></script>
<script src="//cdn.jsdelivr.net/justgage/1.0.1/justgage.min.js"></script>

<h2>
Choose Gage
</h2>

<button id="button1">Gauge 1</button>
<button id="button2">Gauge 2</button>
<div class="gauge1">
  <h2>
Gauge 1
</h2>
  <div id="gauge1" class="200x160px"></div>
</div>
<div class="gauge2">
  <h2>
Gauge 2
</h2>
  <div id="gauge2" class="200x160px"></div>
</div>
```

Comment: Just add `$('.gauge1, .gauge2').hide();` as the first function inside the `$(document).ready()`;

Comment: I tried this but for some reason it prevents gauge1 and gauge2 from ever appearing when either button is pressed.

Comment: I know what to do.

Comment: The plugin actually tries doing the gauging stuff and then it loads. So, when initially hidden, this will not happen. It is better to hide it using `visibility` or just `.hide()` the gauges after the plugin has done its bit and after the plugin has drawn gauges, you can show them. See my answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The plugin actually tries doing the gauging stuff and then it loads. So, when initially hidden, this will not happen. It is better to hide it using `visibility` or just `.hide()` the gauges after the plugin has done its bit and after the plugin has drawn gauges, you can show them:

```
$( document ).ready( function() {

  $( "#button1" ).on( "click" , function() { 
    $('.gauge1').fadeIn();
    $('.gauge2').hide();
  } ) ;

  $( "#button2" ).on( "click" , function() { 
    $('.gauge2').fadeIn();
    $('.gauge1').hide();
  } ) ;


  var d = new JustGage({
    id: "gauge1",
    value: 67,
    min: 0,
    max: 100,
    title: "Visitors"
  });
  var b = new JustGage({
    id: "gauge2",
    value: 91,
    min: 0,
    max: 100,
    title: "Visitors"
  });

  // Add the hide script after the gauges have been drawn.
  $('.gauge1, .gauge2').hide();

} ) ;
```

**Working Fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/q3ysrwfm/**

Answer (score 1):

You're trying to hide the gauges before they're initialised. Move the gauge initialisation up, THEN hide the gauges, i.e.

```
$( document ).ready( function() {

 var d = new JustGage({
    id: "gauge1",
    value: 67,
    min: 0,
    max: 100,
    title: "Visitors"
  });
   var b = new JustGage({
    id: "gauge2",
    value: 91,
    min: 0,
    max: 100,
    title: "Visitors"
  });

$('.gauge1, .gauge2').hide();

  $( "#button1" ).on( "click" , function() { 
   $('.gauge1').fadeIn();
    $('.gauge2').hide();
  } ) ;

    $( "#button2" ).on( "click" , function() { 
   $('.gauge2').fadeIn();
    $('.gauge1').hide();
   } ) ;

  } ) ;
```

Comment: Yeah, I re-read the question and realised he wanted to hide both, not just the first one :)

Comment: @BenG I know what Pub is, I was more like wanna know the context of it here... :P

Comment: @PraveenKumar ha, I think he's asking do you want to go with him

Comment: Sorry, office joke, we pretty much suggest going to the pub for any reason what-so-ever (though oddly enough, we hardly ever go)